# deprecated functionality trim() passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated

Tags: php, deprecated, magento2.4

I'm using Magento 2.4.5, But after installing extension for pincode checker (V4U), I'm getting following error on frontend (While checking pincode ). Can you please help me with this?

```
Deprecated functionality:trim():passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/app/code/V4U/ZipChecker/controller/ZipChecker/ZipChecker.php on line 76
```

Support will be mean a lot to me!

Need to fixed this error, please  help.!

Comment: Are you referring to this [v4u](https://github.com/vrajeshpatel4u/v4u-magento2-check-delivery-availability) ? By the way, have you taken the [tour] and have you read [ask] ?

Comment: Just to check with if else statement $string have value or not(null).

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be triggered in **PHP 8.1** and *later versions* because passing `null` to `string` functions is **deprecated**.

```php
// your code
$result = trim($variable);

// change to this to prevent deprecated warning
$result = trim($variable ?? '');
```

You can test it [using this link](https://onlinephp.io/c/f4fd2)